# get returns null

Tags: c#, .net

I have got some class

```
public static class SessionManager
{
    public static UserSession UserSession
    {
        set
        {                
           HttpContext.Current.Session["USER_SESSION"] = value;
        }
        get
        {
           UserSession userSession = new UserSession();

           try
           {
              userSession = (UserSession)HttpContext.Current.Session["USER_SESSION"];
           }
           catch (Exception)
           {
           }

           return userSession;
       }
   }
}
```

And I am trying  to use it

```
var userSession = SessionManager.UserSession;
```

And the `userSesssion` is always `null`.

Any clue how it can be fixed?

Comment: Are you ever setting it?  If you don't catch and drop the exception in `catch (Exception) {}`, what stacktrace do you see?

Comment: @MikeSamuel There is no any exception at all under `try
                {
                    userSession = (UserSession)HttpContext.Current.Session["USER_SESSION"];
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }`

Comment: is the httpcontext available where you're trying to use it?

Comment: @Peretz, How do you know that?

Comment: @MikeSamuel I put a breakpoint there.

Comment: @Mihai I use it under some  ActionResult method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the pattern you're actually looking for in your property looks more like this:

```
public static class SessionManager
{
    public static UserSession UserSession
    {
        set
        {                
           HttpContext.Current.Session["USER_SESSION"] = value;
        }
        get
        {
            var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
            var userSession = session["USER_SESSION"] as UserSession;

            if (userSession == null)
            {
                userSession = new UserSession ();
                session["USER_SESSION"] = userSession;
            }

            return userSession;
        }
    }
}
```

(I only broke out `var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;` so it would all fit nicely in StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
userSession = (UserSession)(HttpContext.Current.Session["USER_SESSION"]);
```

-or-

```
userSession = HttpContext.Current.Session["USER_SESSION"] as UserSession;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution...

I just forgot to insert under Global.asax.cs

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var userSession = new UserSession();

            SessionManager.UserSession = userSession; 

        }
```

Comment: Then why do you "new" it up inside the property as well?